# Change chartist fill and stroke color in js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chartist.js

Trying to set colors in chartist graph dynamically, but failing to do so.
How can we set custom colors through js ?
Tried doing below but the color is not changing for the showArea in chartist graph.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Chartist</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chartist.min.css">
      <style>
         .ct-series-a .ct-area, .ct-series-a .ct-slice-donut-solid, .ct-series-a .ct-slice-pie{
         fill: #4287f5;
         fill-opacity:0.5;
         stroke: #4287f5;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="ct-chart" id="chart"></div>
      <div class="ct-barchart"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="chartist.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var data = "[49,71,87,135,63]";

         var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
         var chart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
         labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
         series: [
           parsedData
         ]
         }, {
         showPoint: false,
         showLine: false,
         showArea: true,
         fullWidth: true,
         showLabel: false,
         axisX: {
           showGrid: false,
           showLabel: false,
           offset: 0
         },
         axisY: {
           showGrid: false,
           showLabel: false,
           offset: 0
         },
         chartPadding: 0,
         low: 0
         });

         function functioncall(){
             var ta = document.getElementsByClassName('.ct-series .ct-series-a');
            ta[0].style.stroke = "#95f27e";
         }

         functioncall();

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Was only able to change the color through style tag, but i want to do it through js.

Answer (score 0):

The`style` method works with inline styles only. So when you use `ta[0].style.stroke =` style attribute is added to element and style tag is ignored. You may use a css variables with JS (https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript) but use inline style is easier in you case i think.